# OpenLayers pass character parameters problem

Tags: openlayers

I want send character parameter ('GREEN') to GeoServer as following:

```
var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      ratio: 1,
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/newyork/wms',
      params: {         
            "LAYERS": 'newyork:viewStation',
            "viewparams": 'col:'+'GREEN'
      }
    })
  });
```

viewStation is a SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM station WHERE color=%col%
```

but the code doesn't work, I also tried 'col:GREEN'

What can I change?

Comment: If you are passing a string containing a string you will need extra quotes.  SQL prefers single quotes so use double quotes for the javascript wrapper. `"viewparams": "col:" + "'GREEN'"`

Comment: Thank you Mike, but this way of writing still doesn't work

Comment: maybe col is a reserved word wich can be uses , have you tried another variable name (color_from_ol, ...) .

Comment: Thank you Martin, I think it is not a problem with variable name, but when I try to change the name in Geoserver, I found the problem: the default regular expression for 'col' is ^[\w\d\s]+$, It ignores single quotes！So I add the single quote into it as  ^['\w\d\s]+$, it works!

Comment: Please publish your solution in the form of answer to your own question, so it can help others with the similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from professional people. Now the problem is clear. If I want pass character parameter to a SQL view in Geoserver, I should use double quotes and single quotes like this: `"viewparams": "col:" + "'GREEN'"`, where `'GREEN'` is the value I want pass. Meanwhile, on the Geoserver side, I should modify the default regular expression for parameter 'col', add a single quote into it as: `^['\w\d\s]+$`, this way the single quote will not be ignored and the character value be passed successfully.